# Dynamically loading React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm thinking about building a web application, where people can install plugins. I'd like plugins to be able to define React components that will be rendered to the page, without recompiling the main JavaScript bundle after installing the plugin.

So here's the approach I'm thinking of:

- Bundle the main JavaScript with React as an [external library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), using webpack.
- Have plugin authors compile their components with React as an external library as well.

This way, I'm only running one instance of React. I could probably do the same with some other frequently used libraries.

The problem then, is how to dynamically load these plugin components from the server. Let's say I have the following component:

```
class PluginRenderer extends React.Component{
  componentWillMount() {
    getPluginComponent(`/plugins/${this.props.plugin}/component.js`).then((com) => {
      this.setState({pluginComponent: com});
    })
  }

  render() {
    var Plugin = this.state.pluginComponent;
    return Plugin ? <Plugin {...this.props} /> : "Loading..."
  }
}
```

How could `getPluginComponent` be implemented?

Comment: In order to achieve this you'd need server side rendering with NodeJS to access the file system and I am still not sure if it would be possible, bare in mind that the component would still need to be compiled by Babel somehow and that does not happen on runtime.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware the component would still need to be compiled. The compiled source would be served as a static asset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an interesting problem I also faced some months ago for customer work, and I didn't see too many document approaches out there. What we did is:

1. Individual plugins will be separate Webpack projects, for which we provide either a template or a CLI tool that generates project templates.
2. In this project we define Webpack `externals` for shared vendor libraries already used in the core application: React, Redux, etc. This tells the plugin to not include those in the bundle but to grab them from a variable in `window` we set in the core app. I know, sounds like sucks, but it's much better than having all plugins re-include 1000s of shared modules.
3. Reusing this concept of `external`, the core app also provides some services via window object to plugins. Most important one is a `PluginService.register()` method which your plugin must call when it's initialized. We're inverting control here: the plugin is responsible to say "hi I'm here, this is my main export (the Component if it's a UI plugin)" to the core application.
4. The core application has a PluginCache class/module which simply holds a cache for loaded plugins (pluginId -> whatever the plugin exported, fn, class, whatever). If some code needs a plugin to render, it asks this cache for it. This has the benefit of allowing to return a `<Loading />` or `<Error />` component when a plugin did not load correctly, and so on.
5. For plugin loading, this PluginService/Manager loads the plugin configuration (which plugins should I load?) and then creates dynamically injected `script` tags to load each plugin bundle. When the bundle is finished, the `register` call described in step 3 will be called and your cache in step 4 will have the component.
6. Instead of trying to load the plugin directly from your component, ask for it from the cache.

This is a very high level overview which is pretty much tied to our requirements back then (it was a dashboard-like application where users could add/remove panels on the fly, and all those widgets were implemented as plugins).

Depending on your case, you could even wrap the plugins with a `<Provider store={ theCoreStore }`> so they have to access to Redux, or setup an event bus of some kind so that plugins can interact with each other... There is plenty of stuff to figure out ahead. :)

Good luck, hope it helped somehow!

Comment: Can you please describe 2. where you expose your dependencies to window? I'm trying *exactly* the same but I don't know how. I'm losing my hair right now, would be glad if you provide some sample code.

Comment: Hey @BlackHat I simply do something like `window.React = React; window.redux = redux` in my index.js (actually in a separate file which prepares the app reducer and so on). Simply import your dependencies in your main app and reexport in window. Because plugins are loaded asynchronously when they finally are run, they already have the window.XXXX variables ready.

Comment: how do we tell the plugins to use imports from window.* instead of using require()?

Comment: @CharlieBrown Seems I've started along the same lines as you but stuck at point 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447988/react-webpack-render-component-exported-by-external-bundle

Mind expanding on this in more detail for me or providing an example :) ?

Comment: Sure I just did!

Comment: @CharlieBrown How do you import a component from an external url/file?

Comment: @Vetterjack I don't, I load a script and the code in that script calls the PluginService sending by itself the component to "register". Inversion of control. It doesn't care if it's a react component, a function, an object, or whatever. This means that the PluginService itself must be available to the script being loaded: in the global window object.

Comment: @CharlieBrown Thanks for that information, now this whole PluginService makes perfectly sense to me! :)

Comment: Hi all is there any framework or library that helps new comers to achieve the same. That is `async loading of remote ui  components or plugins in main web application`

Answer (score 1):

There is a HOC component that you can import to do this. Components are dynamically loaded as micro apps into your host application.

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

window.React = React;
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// app.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MicroApp from '@schalltech/honeycomb-react-microapp';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MicroApp
        config={{
          View: {
            Name: 'redbox-demo',
            Scope: 'beekeeper',
            Version: 'latest'
          }
        }}
      />
  );
});

export default App;
```

The components are not installed or known at design time. If you get creative, using this approach you could update your components without needing to redeploy your host application.

https://github.com/Schalltech/honeycomb-marketplace#using-micro-apps

Answer (score 0):

I presented [an alternative approach on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130937/2282801). Recapping:

On your app

```js
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */'https://any.url/file.js')
  .then((plugin) => {
    plugin.main({ /* stuff from app plugins need... */ });
  });
```

On your plugin...

```js
const main = (args) => console.log('The plugin was started.');
export { main };
export default main;
```

See more details [on the other question's page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130937/2282801).