# React & Webpack render component exported by external bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to consume a React component that's exposed in an external script *(bundle A)* within my main React app *(bundle B)*.

The external React 'header' component *(bundle A)* is loaded via a `<script>` and exposed as a global window variable using the Webpack [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader).

My site then references the bundles in the following sequence:

1. React/ReactDOM bundle
2. External header component bundle *(bundle A)*
3. Main app bundle *(bundle B)*

The external header component can then be referenced via `window.appHeaderBundle` within the Main app *(bundle B)* e.g.

[image]

Inside my main app, I tried referencing the component like `const Header = window.appHeaderBundle.default;` and then in my `render()` using it as plain jsx `<Header />`.

This does start to run through the component code but blows up with the error:

> Uncaught Error: Element ref was specified as a string (searchForm) but no owner was set. You may have multiple copies of React loaded.

**Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so how can I get my component to render?**

EDIT: This approach does work with a simple component that just renders `<h1>test</h1>`. The use of `ref` is what's breaking things!

---

The idea behind this is that the external bundle can be dropped into multiple sites. Updating the external bundle would then be reflected in all sites. Currently each site loads it via NPM but this requires each site to bump up the version number when a change is made hence why I'm going down this approach.

Comment: I am trying to do similar thing. Is it possible for you to share your webpack config where you use `expose-loader`. I have added script tag to load my external component as a script but not sure how to configure in webpack

Comment: I didn't use expose loader in the end. Bundle A simply assigns the component to a window variable e.g. `window.myComponent = MyComponentName`. So long as your Bundle A is loaded before your main app bundle, you will be able to reference that window variable and use it as a regular component. My own app has checks/fallbacks in place in case of loading issues.

Comment: Tnx. I went ahead with same approach after posting the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you have different copies of React. You should show your webpack configuration for the "plugin" (the external component). In the [answer you commented on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778265/dynamically-loading-react-components), I explained that the webpack configuration for the plugins defined React as being external.

This means of course that your main app should set `window.React = React`before the lazy-loaded components are included, in order for them to work. They shouldn't include React themselves again, that defeats the purpose of having a single React (or more generally a `vendor`) bundle and lazy-loaded components defined as a completely separate Javascript project.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

The error is weird, but it smells like you're not doing this, and thus the Header bundle is including its own copy of React.

Comment: The webpack config for my plugin definitely has external set for React. I've temporarily got it working by removing string refs e.g. `ref="pluginName"` from my plugin components and replacing them with `ref={pluginName => { this.pluginName = pluginName }}`. Accessing `this.pluginName` within my component rather than `this.refs.pluginName` seems to do the trick then

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ran into this error personally, but have you tried doing any of the fixes listed on [this page](https://reactjs.org/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html)?

From your explanation, the way you're using your external component should be possible. I'm not sure that your reasoning for using an external bundle instead of `npm` is good.

- Using `npm` would save an extra HTTP request for this external component.
- What happens when the external component has breaking changes? If the user of this external component doesn't know about it, their web app might break. Using `npm` would prevent this.

Comment: Yep, had a look through that already. No luck yet.

To answer your points, several parts of our website are made up of independent node apps so the external component would be cached on first load. The usage of the external component is very minimal across each app in terms of passing in props.

We need the convenience of updating it in one place over the risk of it breaking certain stuff. We have quite large test coverage to support this.