# React application with external plugins

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, module, parcel

I'm building a React application bundled using Parcel or Webpack.
The application should be able to embed external React components
developed by third-parties and hosted elsewhere as modern javascript modules:

```
// https://example.com/scripts/hello-plugin.js
import React from 'react';

export default class HelloPlugin extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return "Hello from external plugin!";
    }
}
```

Host application loads these components using asynchronous import like this, for example:

```
// createAsyncComponent.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { asyncComponent } from 'react-async-component';

export default function createAsyncComponent(url: string) {
    return asyncComponent({
        resolve: () => import(url).then(component => component.default),
        LoadingComponent: () => <div>Loading {url}....</div>,
        ErrorComponent: ({ error }) => <div>Couldn't load {url}: {error.message}</div>,
    })
}
```

But looks like bundlers don't allow importing arbitrary urls as external javascript modules.

Webpack emits build warnings: "the request of a dependency is an expression" and the import doesn't work. Parcel doesn't report any errors, but fails when import(url) occurs at runtime.

Webpack author recommends using scriptjs or little-loader for loading external scripts.
There is [a working sample](https://gist.github.com/revolunet/cfc6fe0c5992897b29388373a8e51be7) that loads an UMD component from arbitrary URL like this:

```
public componentDidMount() {
    // expose dependencies as globals
    window["React"] = React;
    window["PropTypes"] = PropTypes;

    // async load of remote UMD component
    $script(this.props.url, () => {
        const target = window[this.props.name];
        if (target) {
            this.setState({
                Component: target,
                error: null,
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                Component: null,
                error: `Cannot load component at ${this.props.url}`,
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Also, I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778265/dynamically-loading-react-components) answered a year ago where the suggested approach also involves passing variables via a window object.

But I'd like to avoid using globals given that most modern browsers support modules out of the box.

I'm wondering if it's possible. Perhaps, any way to instruct the bundler that my import(url) is not a request for the code-split chunk of a host application, but a request for loading an external Javascript module.

Comment: Curious about what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of Webpack, you could do something like this:

```js
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */'https://any.url/file.js')
  .then((response) => {
    response.main({ /* stuff from app plugins need... */ });
  });
```

Then your *plugin* file would have something like...

```js
const main = (args) => console.log('The plugin was started.');
export { main };
export default main;
```

Notice you can send stuff from your app's runtime to the plugin at the initialization (i.e. when invoking *main* at the plugin) of the plugins so you don't end up depending on global variables.

You get caching for free as Webpack remembers (caches) that the given URL has already loaded so subsequent calls to import that URL will resolve immediately.

Note: this seems to work in Chrome, Safari & firefox but not Edge. I never bothered testing in IE or other browsers.

I've tried doing this same sort of load with UMD format on the plugin side and that doesn't seem to work with the way Webpack loads stuff. In fact it's interesting that variables declared as globals, don't end up in the window object of your runtime. You'd have to explicitly do `window.aGlobalValue = ...` to get something on the global scope.

Obviously you could also use requirejs - or similar - in your app and then just have your plugins follow that API.

Answer (score -1):

Listen to the Webpack author. You can't do (yet) what you're trying to do with Webpack.

You will have to follow his suggested route.